# Dropdown option list detaching from dropdown in IE

Tags: angular

Dropdown options list detaching from the dropdown when scrolling the page in IE, chrome is working fine. I have attached the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: did you try uncommenting the lines after /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/ in src/polyfills.ts ?

Comment: yeah,i uncommitted in ployfills.ts even though facing same issue